# Reactjs Date Picker

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a customized CSV report download using Reactjs Date picker.
When clicking on Date, from the server side it takes 5 seconds to fetch the data. So during that time , i need to put a loader.

How to put a loader when clicking on the date?

Here is my code:

```
<DatePicker
selected={this.state.startDate}
onChange={this.handleChangeSD}
dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
/>

<DatePicker
selected={this.state.endDate}
onChange={this.handleChangeED}
dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
/>
```

Comment: This may help you: https://www.basefactor.com/react-how-to-display-a-loading-indicator-on-fetch-calls

Answer (score 0):

You can put a spinner. Use the library 'react-epic-spinners'.
Just install it and import it to the following page.
Use a boolean like isLoaded when you fetch the data. Unless you fetch the data boolean must be false. Look the code structure below.

```
render() {
   if(isLoaded){
    return (
        <div  > 
             MAIN CODE HERE
        </div>
    )

   }else{
       return(
        <div > 
            <AtomSpinner color="primary"/>
   </div>
       )
   }
```

}